# How can user inputs be typed in so that I can separate each value by a comma instead of pressing Enter after each value?

Tags: java

Instead of having to press Enter after each value input with Scanner, is there a way to type all values at once, and then press enter and be done?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Arrayex {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int [] numbers = new int[5];

        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Current array: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));

        System.out.println("Type in the numbers: ");
        for(int i=0; i< numbers.length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = s.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Array elements are: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));
    }
}
```

[Current array input by pressing Enter after every number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1fPY.png)

[How I want to type in the numbers into the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ORLp.png)

My friend told me I can use a String array and convert it to int array and type the string as "1,2,3,4,5".
Wouldn't this only use up the location at numbers[0] instead of numbers[0] to numbers[5]?

Comment: Well, **1.** split by comma, and **2.** convert each element to `int`.

Comment: Oh okay, so pretty much what my friend told me.

Thanks.

Comment: @MC if the input is whitespace separated, nothing needs split or parsed

Comment: Indeed, *or* if you use `s.useDelimiter(",|\n")`.

Answer (score 1):

Enter all int elements in one line using space, it will use as separate int values.
it will look like this.
[image]

No need to take input as String and parse it to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

#### (White)space as delimiter

As others have noted, if you just use space as separator, then you could leverage the `Scanner` to convert the input to `int`s. The input `2 3 5 7 11` will yield an `int[]` with the given integers als elements.

#### Comma as delimiter

If you want to use comma as delimiter instead, the current code won't work. The input `2,3,5,7,11` will indeed try to shove `2,3,5,7,11` into `numbers[0]`, which obviously will fail, and an `InputMismatchException` will be thrown at you.

Instead, you could set the delimiter:

```java
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
s.useDelimiter("[,\n]")
```

This will cause the `Scanner` to process the tokens between each comma or newline as separate elements.

Note that we couldn't just use `,` alone, because then the `Scanner` keeps reading from `System.in` indefinitely.